# how to debug app that runs in gcloud shell

Tags: node.js, gcloud

I run a nodejs app in Google cloud shell. now I want to debug this app using google devtools by `node --inspect` flag.

I know how to use this feature with an app that runs locally, but I want to use this feature with an app that runs in gcloud shell as if it runs locally.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I've not tried this!</strike>

This approach works; I was unfamiliar with `node --inspect` but am able to remotely debug a Cloud Shell VM running a gRPC server using it (thanks for the intro!)

> **NOTE** You don't need to determine the Cloud Shell VM's IP

When you start Cloud Shell using `gcloud cloud-shell ssh`, you can append `--verbosity=debug` to determine the instance's IP. 

When you run Cloud Shell, port-forward to 8080 (IIRC Cloud Shell permits traffic on `8080` and maybe other ports.):

```sh
gcloud cloud-shell ssh \
--ssh-flag="-L 8080:localhost:8080"
```

> **NOTE** I'm unsure how you can determine the Cloud Shell instance's IP using the browser client.

Then you can probably run:

```
node \
--inspect=0.0.0.0:8080 \
--enable-source-maps \
your-javascript-file
```

From your localhost (!) Chrome DevTools you can `chrome://inspect` and add a connection for `localhost:8080` (`localhost` because the Cloud Shell port is being forwarded to your localhost).

Here's the local Chrome DevTools Console showing logs from a Cloud Shell hosted gRPC server:

[image: gRPC Server]

Answer (score 0):

Please check official Google documentation about it

[Cloud Debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/nodejs#gae-flex)